# Testing Restful services not showing in Firefox

Tags: java, firefox, testing, rest, netbeans

I am using netbeans 6.8 and glass fish and trying to start learning restful services.
I made a simple Restful services using "patterns" and choose singletone (single root). Other thngs were default. I know most of the things the ide did.

Then I modified the class to provide client to use URL http://host:8080/resources/generic/Name
 and it would produce application/xml file with "hello {NAME} "

Ok, I deployed this application and then Tested Restful services.
I opened it in Firefox 6.0. But the thing that got displayed was:

> wsdl file complete link

and one line  "and nothing else below it."

> Select a node on the navigation bar (on the left side of this page) to test.

As I found that there should had been some more content to test.
Thanks in advance. :)

**EDIT**: It's working in Internet Explorer ... is there anything to add in my Firefox?